# Replicating remote site "attack" by force sending specific form data to a page

Tags: asp-classic

I have this simple form:

```
<form  method="post" id="theForm" action="user-password.asp">
    <input type="hidden" name="what" value="process" />
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Username or Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Username or Email" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success top10">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have a script which emails me when my Classic ASP pages error - I use this to get all of the form contents:

```
For ix = 1 to Request.Form.Count
    fieldName = Request.Form.Key(ix)
    fieldValue = Request.Form.Item(ix)
    bb = bb & fieldName & ": " & fieldValue & vbcrlf
Next

bb = newstr(bb)
```

For the above page, the page errored with:

*A trappable error (C0000005) occurred in an external object. The script cannot continue running.*

The form contents were like this:

```
form: email[$acunetix]: 1
what: process
```

In order to improve the error handling on the page, I'd like to be able to replicate loading the form with whatever it was that was used to generate the form input which made the page error - in the above example the form field name is not `email` but is `email[$acunetix]`, which seems to have broken the page when it tries to process the form.

However, I don't know what was done to do that. The same IP address spent about 40 minutes forcing all kinds of stuff onto my pages which eventually crashed my site requiring a server reboot.

I realise that is down to me not writing robust enough code - but - I wondered how I can replicate sending the form data shown above to the page, as I'm stuck trying to work out how to do that.

Comment: I'd recommend [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/), but I assume you're using windows so you might want to check out [Postman](https://www.postman.com/).

Comment: Have you tried altering the name using javascript in the console for the email-field to email[$acunetix] before sending it? Chances are that the attacker added some values to $acunetix and tried to send them on as a variable using the name rather than the actual value of the field. Probably hoping that it was used somewhere unparameterized. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @DanielNordh - thank you for your reply! To be honest I don't know how to do that re. changing the name using JS. I've been into Inspect Element and can see I can change the name there, but does that impact how the actual form would submit? I'd like to try and replicate this type of scenario, but I am new to knowing how to do this. All the user inputted data is parameterised in terms of how it's plugged into SQL queries, but something else must be tripping the page up. Thanks again

Comment: @4532066 I believe it depends on how you're actually submitting the data. If you're fetching the data from hardcoded field names, then it wouldn't work since no fieldname would match what you're trying to do. The way you're collecting the form data it looks like you're doing it dynamically so it's quite possible that someone could send data through the variable name rather than the value itself. I've honestly never tried what I am talking about, so I could just be giving unhelpful ideas, but it's something I would at the very least test to see what happens. Try changing with inspect element.

Comment: Stop using dynamically assigned values instead, be explicit `Request.Form("email")` avoids script kiddies sending through any fields they wish. Also naming a form processing page `user-password.asp` is asking for trouble.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply @Lankymart - in the `For ix = 1 to Request.Form.Count` example, that is just what I use on the error_500.asp page which is called when an ASP page errors. On the actual page which errored, I do use `request.form("email")` - I just used the For ix... code so that I can see what data was loaded into the form for the page which errored.